# more than 3 entries in the column

Tags: sql

I have a table say XYZ, there are three entries for each entity of the column say 'a' and I want to find out if there are more than 3 entries for those entities in the column.

column:

```
    a      b      c
    123
    123
    123
    sol
    sol
    sol
    456
    456
    456
```

Here I want to know if I have more than 3 entries for 123 or sol or 456 in the tab

Comment: Have you tried something straightforward like SELECT COUNT(a) as 'Count-of-A' FROM XYZ GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(a) = 3

Answer (score 1):

Just try somthing like this, i did not test the sql but you understand the ideea

```
select a 
from your_table 
where 
   (select count(*) 
    from your_table 
    where a = 'your_entity') > 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT a, count(a) from YOURTABLE group by a having count(a) > 2`
Since you didn't provide a table name i just placed "YOURTABLE" there.

Comment: Why `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`? This is a performance killer!

Comment: AFAIK you can't have COUNT() in a WHERE clause. At least I get an error if I try to.

Comment: It's doable the way Dan suggests though.

Comment: In the end it's the questioner who picks the snippet which fits him best. But thank you for advising us that HAVING is [less performant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328636/which-sql-statement-is-faster-having-vs-where).