# Having OR Where, Which is Faster in performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I used 'Having' as 'Where' (i.e. without group by clause), 
Can you please tell me which one is faster ‘Where’ OR ‘Having (as where)’? 
Which one we have to prefer?

Scenario - I am using this condition in finding locations in certain distance using lat and longitude.

Comment: Actually you can do your own benchmark.

Comment: What RDBMS are you actually using? `HAVING` and `WHERE` aren't generally interchangeable as `HAVING` applies to groups and `WHERE` on rows.

Comment: If we remove 'group by' clause from having it works like a Where. That means both queries will give same result. So my question is which one is faster?

Comment: Why would you want to use a `having` clause if you don't use `group by`. Makes no sense

Comment: I presume you are not on SQL Server then so have removed that tag. In SQL Server you would get `Column 'foo' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Yes, I am using MySQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which SQL statement is faster? (HAVING vs. WHERE...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328636/which-sql-statement-is-faster-having-vs-where)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Actually there are two scenario in finding near location using lat and long. In one we are calculating distance from source to destination location. In this case I just put 'Having dist > 200'.       but there is one more way to get lat and long range, here if we pass it in 'where lat >= lat_calucated and lng <= lng_calucated.   it gives same result. and that is the reason I am asking above question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a condition refers to an `aggregate` function, put that condition in the `HAVING` clause. Otherwise, use the `WHERE` clause.

You can use `HAVING` but recommended you should use with `GROUP BY`.

`SQL Standard` says that `WHERE` restricts the result set before returning rows and `HAVING` restricts the result set after bringing all the rows. So `WHERE` is faster.

Comment: "You can't use HAVING unless you also use GROUP BY." - I dont think so. We can use Having without 'group by'. But I think I got answer in your last sentence.

Comment: @Abhi but recommended use with `Group By`

Comment: Actually there are two scenario in finding near location using lat and long. In one - we are calculating distance from source to destination location. In this case I just put 'Having dist > 200'. but there is one more way to get lat and long range, here if we pass it in 'where lat >= lat_calucated and lng <= lng_calucated. it gives same result. and that is the reason I am asking above question. Which one I have to prefer?

Comment: @Abhi How could you get rows by distance from location just by specifying let>=lat_calc and lng<=lng_calc? when you search for location you always specify region (you can specify acceptable (calculated) ranges for lat and lng for searching in rectangle or calculating distance of two points and filtering it by having desired distance)...I'm afraid that getting same results is just coincidence. Isn't it?

Comment: @GrizzlyNetch Please check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj133823.aspx                                        SELECT userID FROM tblUsers WHERE latitude >= 47.0 AND latitude < 48.0 AND longitude >= -123.0 AND longitude < -122.0 - it will not return duplicate records.

Comment: @Abhi "latitude >= 47.0 AND latitude < 48.0 AND longitude >= -123.0 AND longitude < -122.0" is fine (it's search by bounding box I've referenced as specifying ranges, similar to say "latitude BETWEEN 47 AND 48 AND longitude BETWEEN -123 AND -122" – although "BETWEEN 0 AND 1" is not exactly same as ">=0 AND <1"). The confusion for me was the incomplete condition "WHERE lat >= lat_calucated and lng <= lng_calucated" :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference between `HAVING` and `WHERE`:
[HAVING without GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924896/having-without-group-by)
You can not in general use it alternatively, but all about it is covered in this link

And here is the topic about their speed: [Which SQL statement is faster? (HAVING vs. WHERE...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328636/which-sql-statement-is-faster-having-vs-where)

Answer (score 0):

The use of HAVING and WHERE are not interchangeable. They cover different topics, HAVING only seems equal to WHERE if there is not GROUP BY sentence

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause                 check this. If you dont use 'group by', 'Having' will work like 'Where'.